# Possible Grammar Error

Tags: grammar

I asked a friend of mine to read something (on skype), and he declined the offer.

Then he asked me to play a game, to which I replied, "I have better things to do."

Then he wrote back, "Exactly! Why I didn't read."

Then we got into a debate about whether it was grammatically correct.

I believe that if he had said "Exactly why I didn't read your text", it would have been correct or even something like "Exactly why I didn't read", but he says he is correct.

Can you tell me whether he is mistaken or I am?

Comment: I thought you had better things to do... :P

Comment: Neither one of you had time to do something the other asked you to do, but each of you had time to argue about something trivial. Lovely.

Comment: Its because I asked him what "Exactly! Why I didn't read." meant then he insulted me so I felt the need to defend myself.

Answer (score 2):

He is mistaken. A correct formulation would be (notice the *that*):

> That is exactly why I didn't read your text.

*Why I didn't read* cannot stand by itself because it lacks an object (*that* and *text* in the above example).

Comment: terdon, so you think that the (indirect) object is not 'text', but 'that'?

Comment: @Carlo_R. I am saying that _I didn't read_ has no object.

Comment: ...making it a phrase or sentence fragment instead of a full sentence because it was missing an object.

Comment: terdon, I think you need to clarify your last sentence, removing grammar ambiguity; otherwise you run the risk of having the answer downvoted.

Comment: @Carlo_R. better?

Comment: terdon, sorry, but I don't understand sentences made by one word, even if they end with the question mark.

Comment: @Carlo_R. strictly speaking, that is not a sentence :). I meant "Is my answer better now that I have edited it?". I hope you did not interpret my one word answer to mean that I was snapping at you, it was not meant that way.

Comment: terdon, OK, +1!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this.

You're friends, so grammatical flexibility exists between you. It's fun to play with language, or maybe he was trying to be more efficient.

Grammatically it's no good and it shouldn't go in an essay, but don't be so hard on the guy! If you pay close enough attention, you'll see people make these kinds of mistakes in speech and online chatting all the time. In most cases, no one notices, and even if they do they forget about it soon enough. This is because we're capable of filling in the missing pieces in most situations and can understand 'broken up' or 'incomplete' transmissions for this reason.

It wastes a lot of time to be nit-picky about this with a fluent speaker. By definition he knows how to speak English perfectly, and therefore also knows what rules can and cannot be bent. He may say something like "why I didn't read" instead of "that's why I didn't read your thing" but he would *never* say "read I why didn't".

This is the distinction between "descriptive" and "prescriptive" grammars, essentially. English papers (and all academic/official writing) uses prescriptive grammar, in which the rules are created to be followed. Conversation and other informal language uses descriptive grammar, in which the rules are innate and up in your brain already, and it's the job of a linguist to figure them out!